# Can you use php with an SQL case?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I am trying to optimize some of my code and i believe i need an if/else or case to do this, however I think i would need php in the query to get it to work

here is the code I am trying to optimize

```
    $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
    ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
    GROUP BY age_id; ";

if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
    ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
    AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . "
    GROUP BY age_id; ";
} else if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 || $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
    ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
    AND (year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " OR month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . ")
    GROUP BY age_id; ";
}
```

and this is what I have tried to give you a rough idea of what I am trying to achieve

```
$filter = "";

if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $filter = "AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . ""
} else if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 || $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $filter = "AND (year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " OR month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . ")"
}

$sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
CASE 
    WHEN ".isset($filter)." THEN ". $filter ."
END
GROUP BY age_id; ";
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You should also think about prepared statements.

Comment: is it valid to use PHP with a case in my attempt above?

Comment: Are you asking about a `CASE` in PHP (`switch`) or a `CASE` in MySQL?

Comment: In MySQL, I am trying to find a way to optimize my code

Comment: Of course you can use `CASE` with PHP, however I never see `CASE` used in the condition like you're doing, but rather in the values. On top of that, I don't think this is a case for `CASE`.  Just add your `$filter` var: `$office_id . $filter`.

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work however now it does?? i must have made a mistake somewhere, this works fine too, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up an array of filters depending on which values (year, month, etc) are set, and then combine them all into the WHERE clause. You don't need to worry about all the separate cases where both are set, or one are set, and so on.

I would also strongly echo the advice above that recommended looking into prepared statements, but this will hopefully get you on your way.

```
<?php
$office_id = 10;
$_SESSION['filteryear'] = 2016;
$_SESSION['filtermonth'] = 12;

$filters = [
    "value IS NOT NULL",
    "office_id = {$office_id}",
];

if ($_SESSION['filteryear']) {
    $filters[] = "year = {$_SESSION['filteryear']}";
}

if ($_SESSION['filtermonth']) {
    $filters[] = "month = {$_SESSION['filtermonth']}";
}


$sql = "
    SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM sodsurvey
    LEFT JOIN age ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id
    WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $filters) . "
    GROUP BY age_id;
";
```

The [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) line combines each filter that's been set into a single WHERE clause.

Comment: This works, thanks, i'm trying to understand, am I correct in saying that if both conditions are true would the final SQL result in something like this ( "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
            ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
            WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = 10
            year = 2016
            month = 12
            GROUP BY age_id; " ) ?

Comment: Yes, if both are set then the SQL will contain both conditions. If only one is set, then only that one will be used.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Answer (score 1):

> is it valid to use PHP with a case in my attempt above?

No. PHP code cannot be part of your SQL query, however your PHP code can **generate** SQL query

> In MySQL, I am trying to find a way to optimize my code

Just make your SQL code generated by PHP code based on all the conditions. You can easily concatenate strings being partions of your query conditionally.